# Does AIR on iPhone have a 1024x1024 (2048x2048) limit on the images it can load?

Tags: flash, air

The iPhone does. Does AIR/Flash?

Comment: There is no Flash and no AIR available on the iPhone. So technically, there's no limit...

Comment: @Holger, AIR apps can be compiled as stand-alone apps for iOS. Flash Player or the AIR runtime as such can not be installed on iOS, but ActionScript and other aspects of the development tools for the Flash platform can be used to develop stand-alone apps. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices/ios.html

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone doesn't have a limit on image size any more. It *used* to, but that was way back in iOS 2. Since 3.0 there has been no finite limit on the size of images or `UIViews` generally.

The only limit is one of memory. So loading a 2048x2048 PNG is a bad idea, because it's going to consume around 16MB of memory once uncompressed. One some iOS hardware you may only have 80MB or less to play with, so that's a substantial chunk.

This memory constraint is independent of software, so using Adobe AIR isn't going to let you have larger images than using raw Objective-C.

If you need to display large images on memory constrained devices such as the iPhone you need to think about smart ways of doing so, such as through tiling.